# Unzip a password protect zip file using cmd in windows

Tags: command-line, power-supply, cmd.exe

Is there any way i can extract contents from a .zip folder that is password protected using command line.

Comment: Do you know the password? are you looking to "crack" the password to access the content or do you wish to to script the extraction.

Comment: i know the password, just want to do extraction

Answer (score 3):

You can use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

```
7z x Yourzipfilfe.zip -pYourPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options. Check the suitable documentation for the tool you want to use. One example would be `unrar` which does support supplying password and should be able to extract a password protected zip.

Comment: I want to use the default one that is already there in the OS. I am using 2016 datacenter

Comment: PowerShell doesn't support it, I'm unaware of how to call that function on the cmd to even extract a non protected zip, so you will probably be out of luck. For more examples have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021557/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-command-line). It also has at least one hint about the built-in functionality, though it's far from being easy to use (in comparison).